# Why does Caret featurePlot returns returns NULL?

Tags: r

I am trying to use `featurePlot` of `caret` in R.

This is the code I am using:

```
trellis.par.set(theme = col.whitebg(), warn = FALSE) 
caret::featurePlot(x = df[, 3:6], 
            y = df$ud, 
            plot = "scatter")
```

where all the columns of `df[, 3:6]`are of numeric type, while `df$ud` is a binary factor.

I also have installed the library `ellipse` as suggested elsewhere.

However, I keep getting `NULL`.

Any idea why?

Comment: Take a look at help(featurePlot) in caret for the expected class of the argument, x, which is a matrix

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem due to my y variable not being a factor which is required. call:

```
typeof(df$ud)
```

make sure it is not interpreting the binary as character or numeric but indeed ad a factor.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by converting the `Y` variable to a factor. Add `as.factor()` to your `Y` variable. So your code should look like:

```
trellis.par.set(theme = col.whitebg(), warn = FALSE) 
caret::featurePlot(x = df[, 3:6], 
            y = as.factor(df$ud), 
            plot = "scatter")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my dataset. The issue was with my character column. For using featurePlot you have to pass **only numeric and factor** as you independent variables and dependent variable. You can use `str()` function to check your dataframe and then use `as.factor()` in order to change character to factor.

For example: the **Purchase** variable in my dataframe was in character type so I use below code to change it into factor type.

```
traindata$Purchase <- as.factor(traindata$Purchase)
```

after that featurePlot worked fine.